# Return id from combined functions

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm trying to optimize a platform I created, and removing code that maybe aren't necessary. and since I started read about PHP classes and decided to rewrite the entire function page.

I'm having two functions for my login page.

```
valid_credientials($email,$password){} and
function fetch_user_id($email){ }
```

the `fetch_user_id` returns the id from logged in user, so my session would change from session email to session uid.

Now Am i trying to combine this two function, but i get only error messages so i was thinking, that maybe i need this two function ? 
This is what i have for now.

```
public function valid_credientials($email,$password){

if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
$query =    $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email=? AND password=?" );

$query->    bindParam(1, $email);
$query->    bindParam(2, $password);
$query->    execute();

if($query->rowCount() == 1){
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $row[id];
        echo "user verified Access granted";
}
}else{
    echo 'Wrong Username of password';} 
}
```

}

```
function fetch_user_id($email){
global $db;
$query = $db->query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'");
$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $row[id];
}
```

As you see am i trying to use the $row = query inside the valid_credential function.
but it only returns error - undefined constant id - assumed 'id' in.

thanks!

Comment: I read your question over 3 times but still can't get your problem, save for obvious [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) and absence of [fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) which have to be used in your functions

Comment: What exactly you are trying to combine?

Comment: @YourCommonSense hey, was out for dinner :)
I'm trying to combine fetch_user_id($email) with my public function valid_credientials() so it will return my ID, for now its only returning my email.
If i write $_SESSION['email'] = $email; inside the valid_credential function, it returns me the email so my logging path becomes, profile.php?uid=myemail@email.com
But ofcourse I would like the function to give me the path .php?uid=ID.

I know i suck on explaining, but I'm still learning.

Comment: what's the reason for combining these 2 functions?

Comment: its really for minimize using of function, but i think Im on to something here. hey will probably come back in a couple of hours with questions :(.
but thanks :)

Comment: I dont understand the way these functions can be combined. they are totally different, aren't they?